click sth. button to show select options
I want to show the select options when i click sth. button
i try:
    <button id="showSelect">show</button>
    <select id="mySelect">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
   <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#showSelect').on('click', () => {
                $('#mySelect').focus()
            })
        });
    </script>

 It doesn't work.....
then i try:
    <button id="showSelect">show</button>
    <select id="mySelect">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
   <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#showSelect').on('click', () => {
                $('#mySelect').trigger('click')
            })
        });
    </script>

 It doesn't work too.....damn!!
so, how can i do.....

what is sth. button?

to be honest you shouldn't do this. Check out showPicker() if you really insist

showPicker is useable!  tks!!! @LãNgọcHải

@JaromandaX It's just any button~
